# How can I properly re-write C++11 lambda expression without lambda expr

Tags: c++11, lambda, functor

I have a following code:

```
class Variant
{
public:
    void init();
}

void Variant::init()
{
    int var 1;
    vector list;
    vector list2;

    tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<std::size_t>(0, list.size(), ClrSize),
    [this, &var1, &list,&list2](const tbb::blocked_range<std::size_t> &range)
    {
        /*some code here*/
    }
```

I thought about implementing `operator()(const tbb::blocked_range<std::size_t> &range)`

```
class Variant
{
public:
    void operator()(const tbb::blocked_range<std::size_t> &range)
    {
        /*some code here*/
    }
    void init();
}

void Variant::init()
{
    int var 1;
    vector list;
    vector list2;

    tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<std::size_t>(0, list.size(), ClrSize), this);
}
```

but it doesn't solve capture list problem.

How I can re-write lambda expression? What can I do with *var1, list, list2* arguments?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You capture in the constructor of the functor you're making, and pass the capture variables as arguments to the constructor. It's easiest to use a separate class, rather than trying to reuse the object you exist in.

```
class MyFunctor
{
    Variant& x; int& y; vector& z; vector& foo;
public:
    MyFunctor(Variant& x, int& y, vector& z, vector& foo) : x(x), y(y), z(z), foo(foo) {};
    void operator()(const tbb::blocked_range<std::size_t> &range)
    {
        /* use x, y, z and foo here */
    }
}
```

then have `init` make an instance of `MyFunctor` to pass.

Comment: Did you mean I should use code like this ? *tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<std::size_t>(0, list.size(), ClrSize), MyFunctor(x, y, z, foo))*

Comment: @Deachy: Well, in your case, I think the arguments passed to `MyFunctor` would be `*this, var1, list, list2`, but yeah, that's the idea; C++11 lambdas are just syntactic sugar for anonymous definitions of functors that bind variables (arguments to the constructor that become members of the functor instance) and provide an `operator()` method that can use those captured variables.